# Percentile over in a Window function in Amazon Athena

Tags: sql, window-functions, amazon-athena, percentile-cont

I am searching for a solution for a problem. I am working with Amazon Athena and i need a field that shows the percentile of days for a product between 2 timestamps. I have it working in Amazon Quicksight but because of the Limit to aggregate there i can´t use the results in other calculated fields. So my only option is to build the field in as a SQL statement directly into my dataset. But when i try to build it it always gives me errors.

I tried following statements:

```
approx_percentile(case when (date_diff('millisecond', b.zp8_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24)<0)OR (date_diff('millisecond', b.zp8_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24) >200) then null else date_diff('millisecond', b.zp8_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24)end,20) OVER (werkziel) 

case when (date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfein_ts,b.vhfaus_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24)<0)OR (date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfein_ts,b.vhfaus_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24) >200) then null else Percentile_count(date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfein_ts,b.vhfaus_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24)) OVER (PARTITION BY concat(c.pk_nr_werk_num2,c.zielort_id),20) end
```

And this is the calculated field from Amazon Quicksight which is working: `percentileCont({zp8_depein_90},20,[werkziel])`

Sample Data:

| zp8_ts | depein_ts | pk_num_werk_num2 | zielort_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 05 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 11 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC44 L |
| 01.01.2022 | 05.01.2022 | 15 | ABC08 L |

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output.

Comment: desired outcome is a percentile number for all products that have the same werkziel field. I sadly can´t put in  sample data for confidality reasons. 
The timestamps are just timestamps and the werkziel is a 12 letter long string that was made by a concat function from the factory number and the destination id if that helps.

Comment: _"I sadly can´t put in sample data for confidality reasons"_ - then put some sample (generated/not real) data which  will show the problem.

Comment: I put a picture of sample data here. I could not find an option to add an excel file

Comment: Please do not post sample data/code/errors as picture. Almost always (except for some rare cases) those are text, post them as text.

Comment: I added the sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this problem. There was a particion by missing after the over.

```
approx_percentile(
CASE WHEN ( 
  date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfaus_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24) < 0
  ) OR (
    date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfaus_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24) >200
  ) THEN NULL 
  ELSE date_diff('millisecond', b.vhfaus_ts,b.depein_ts) / (1E3 *3600 *24) end, 0.8) OVER (**PARTITION by** concat(c.pk_nr_werk_num2,c.zielort_id)
) AS vhfaus_depein_p80,
```